# Google Sheets: Using data validation custom formula to reject alphanumeric below a certain number

Tags: google-sheets

I've created a shared Google spreadsheet which tracks a sales rep contest for work. There is a column in my spreadsheet which requires the reps to enter in an alphanumeric code which tallies at the bottom. The problem is that some reps are using old codes which shouldn't be accepted, and I have to manually comb the spreadsheet at the end of every 6 months to make sure no one has cheated the system (there are money prizes involved).

I'm looking for some help to build a data validation formula which will achieve two things:

1. Reject any alphanumeric numbers below BR052300 (ex. BR040000 should be rejected, BR053000 is OK)
2. Reject duplicate entries

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try something like:

```
=and(1*right(A1,5)>52299,countif(A$1:A1,A1)=1)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!!